# Inserting bulk data into odoo.com. using python

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, odoo-11, odoo-12

hello i am new to odoo platform.

I have few scripts which extracting data from some websites and i want to modify all by adding functionality that data will be directly uploaded to odoo shop or odoo website.
i want to know that is there any way by which i can upload bulk data into odoo platform using python programming.

I have few scripts which are xtracting information from ecommerce websites and using python scrapy for that. now need some solution to upload this data to odoo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Odoo 12.0, the `create` method supports batch creation like so:

```
vals_list = [{'name': 'john doe'}, {'name': 'alan turing'}, ...]
self.env['model.name'].create(vals_list)
```

The ORM will take care of writing the SQL `INSERT` to do this.